# Pure JavaScript: Combine onload and onresize in one function?

Tags: javascript

A bit stuck here.

I'm trying to display and output the live(responsive) height and width of the inner page.

In this code, I feel like I am repeating myself to much. Is there anyway to make the code look cleaner or put it in one function?

Personally, I don't want to use JQuery in this case.

```js
var pageSize = document.getElementById("innerSize");

window.onload = function() {
  var w = document.documentElement.clientWidth;
  var h = document.documentElement.clientHeight;

  pageSize.innerHTML = "Width: " + w + "<br>" + " Height: " + h;
}

window.onresize = function() {
  var w = document.documentElement.clientWidth;
  var h = document.documentElement.clientHeight;

  pageSize.innerHTML = "Width: " + w + "<br>" + " Height: " + h;
}
```

```html
<div id="innerSize"></div>
```

Comment: Write a single function and assign it to both onload and onresize

Answer (score 8, accepted):

> In this code, I feel like I am repeating myself to much. Is there anyway to make the code look cleaner or put it in one function?

Yes, you are repeating yourself too much.  Set the same functions all in one go (or split them up in separate lines -- coders choice), either way, set them to the same function.

```js
var pageSize = document.getElementById("innerSize");

window.onload = window.onresize = setWidth;

function setWidth() {
  var w = document.documentElement.clientWidth;
  var h = document.documentElement.clientHeight;

  pageSize.innerHTML = "Width: " + w + "<br>" + " Height: " + h;
}
```

```html
<div id="innerSize"></div>
```